# Does using Tables in Twitter Bootstrap 3 prevents UI from being responsive?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm switching from bootstrap 2.3.2 to bootstrap 3. Is using tables tr, td tags make design it difficult to make design responsive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It of course depends, but generally tables are not recommended to be used when implementing a responsive design.

Answer (score 0):

You could follow solution described here to get a responsive design for tables as well. It recreates rows with column header, column value.

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/no-more-tables-respsonsive-table

No more tables (responsive table)

[image: Original Table]

Into

[image: Mobile Responsive Restructured Table]